# JFace TableViewer - how to properly fireSelectionChanged() after calling setInput(...)?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I have an editor in an RCP Program that contains a `TableViewer`. The content of the `TableViewer` can be updated as the result of an `Action` in the editor. This is currently done by creating the new input and calling

```
tableViewer.setInput(updatedInput);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't send a `SelectionChangedEvent` until either the editor loses focus or a new selection is made in the table. This leads to trouble in a `Command` which gets the current selection via `HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event)` -

```
ISelection oldSelection = tableViewer.getSelection();
Collection<Foo> newFoos = fooAction.createNewFoos();
tableViewer.setInput(newFoos);
...
...//call an action.
...//Inside the action:
Collection<Foo> selectedFoos = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event).toList();
//No good! We get the unchanged selection back!
```

I see two ways to solve this problem. Iterating through the input and adjusting the existing objects instead of calling `setInput()` would probably work, but is not an option in my case. Instead, I want to trigger a `SelectionChangedEvent`, which will get `HandlerUtil` to update its `currentSelection` variable. Currently, I get this to happen like this:

```
ISelection oldSelection = tableViewer.getSelection();
Collection<Foo> newFoos = fooAction.createNewFoos();
tableViewer.setInput(newFoos);
ISelection selection = tableViewer.getSelection();
tableViewer.setSelection(null);
tableViewer.setSelection(selection);
```

This works, as the selection changes, which forces an event to be fired off. But it's also an ugly hack, and even with a comment I think this could potentially confuse anyone looking at this chunk of code in the future.

So with all that out of the way, is there a proper way to get a `TableViewer` to fire a `SelectionChangedEvent`? Could I maybe get this to happen automatically with the proper `ContentProvider`? Or can I somehow accomplish this by firing a property change from the view or editor?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is fine except that you should set the selection to empty rather than null with:

```
tableViewer.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);
```